# С++ Как обратиться к методу под класса, если основной юзает шаблон

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Проблема заключается в том что непонятно каким образом описать (прототипы) методов, имеются методы которые возвращают объекты под класса и не понятно как описать данный метод когда не использовался шаблон достаточно было написать List::Node и всё работало
Например:

```
 List::Node * List::find (int d){
  Node *pv = pbeg;
  while(pv){
    if (pv->d == d) break;
    pv = pv->next;
  }
  return pv;
}
```

Но при введении шаблона таким образом обратиться не выходит:

main.h

```
 #ifndef MAIN_H_
    #define MAIN_H_
      #include <iostream>
      #include "list.h"
    #endif
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int main(){
  List <int> L;
  for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) L.add(i);
   L.print();
  // L.print_back();
  // L.insert(2,200); //error
  // if (!L.remove(3)) std::cout<< " not found";
  // L.print();

  // L.print_back();
  return 0;
}
```

//list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_
template <class Data> class List{
 class Node{
   public:
     Data d; // Данные
     Node *next; // Указатель на последующий узел
     Node *prev; // Указатель на предыдущий узел
     //constructor
     Node (Data);
 };

 Node *pbeg, *pend; // Указатели на начало и конец списка
public:
 List(); // constructor
 ~List(); // destructor
 void add(Data d); // Добавление узла в конец списка
 Node * find(Data i); // Поиск узла по ключу
 //Вставка узла d после узла с ключом key:
 Node * insert(Data key, Data d);
 bool remove(Data key); // Удаление узла
 void print(); // Печать списка в прямом направлении
 void print_back(); /// Печать списка в обратном порядке
};

#include "List.hpp"

#endif
```

//list.hpp

```
#ifndef LIST_HPP_
#define LIST_HPP_

#include "main.h"


template <class Data>
List<Data>::Node::Node (Data d) {
  this->d = d;
  next = 0;
  prev = 0;
}

template <class Data>
List<Data>::List(){
  pbeg = 0;
  pend = 0;
}

template <class Data>
void List<Data>::add(Data d){
  Node *pv = new Node(d); //выделение памяти под новый узел
  if (pbeg == 0) pbeg = pend = pv;
  else{
    // Связывание нового узла с предыдущим:
    pv->prev = pend;
    pend->next = pv;
    pend = pv; // Обновление уазателия на конец списка
  }
}

template <class Data>
  List<Data>::Node * List<Data>::find (Data d){
  Node *pv = pbeg;
  while(pv){
    if (pv->d == d) break;
    pv = pv->next;
  }
  return pv;
}

template <class Data>
List::Node * List<Data>::insert(Data key, Data d){
  if (Node * pkey = find (key)){ // Поиск узла с ключом key
    //Выделение памяти под новый узел и его инициализация
    Node *pv = new Node(d);
    // Установление связи нового узла с последющим
    pv->next = pkey->next;
    // Установление связи нового узла с предыдущим
    pv->prev = pkey;
    // Установление связи последющего узла с новым
    pkey->next = pv;
    // Установление связи последующего узла с новым
    if ( pkey != pend) (pv->next)->prev = pv;
    //Обновление указателя на конец списка
    // если узел вставляется на конец списка:
    else pend = pv;
    return pv;
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class Data>
bool List<Data>::remove(Data key){
  if(Node * pkey = find(key)){
    if (pkey == pbeg) { // Удаление из начала списка
        pbeg = pbeg->next;
        pbeg->prev = 0;
    }
    else if (pkey == pend){ // Удаление из конца списка
        pend = pend->prev;
        pend->next = 0 ;
    }
    else{ // Удаление из средины списка
        (pkey->prev)->next = pkey->next;
        (pkey->next)->prev = pkey->prev;
    }
    delete pkey;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <class Data>
void List<Data>::print(){
  Node *pv = pbeg;
  std::cout<<std::endl<<"list: ";
  while (pv){
    std::cout<<pv->d<<' ';
    pv =pv->next;
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template <class Data>
void List<Data>::print_back(){
  Node *pv = pend;
  std::cout<<std::endl<<"list end: ";
  while (pv){
    std::cout<<pv->d<<' ';
    pv =pv->prev;
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template <class Data>
List <Data>::~List(){
  if (pbeg != 0){
    Node *pv = pbeg;
    while (pv){
      pv = pv->next;
      delete pbeg;
      pbeg = pv;
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

//MakeFile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp List.hpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=list

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

//Errors

mingw32-make -f .\MakeFile

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то я не понял: вы говорили про производный класс - а где у вас наследование?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ошибки не сложные, и компмлятор достаточно внятно ругается.

Comment: Да извиняюсь что-то в голове осталось недавно читал про наследование, если есть возможность сейчас изменю, я понимаю что компилятор внятно ругается я понимаю на что он ругается, суть в том что я не понимаю каким образом мне обратиться к типу Node чтоб он понял что я от него хочу я пробовал многими способами сюда пишу в последнею очередь в гугле искал схожих примеров не нашёл.

Comment: @bipll тут я не соглашусь, так как может быть не понятно на что он ругается. Создается впечатление, что просто не обьявлен template<typename>, хотя он есть - это вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В смысле? В одном случае требует typename перед List<Data>::Node, потому что автоматически считать  такое типом в таком контексте еще не принято, в другом случае жалуется, что List без параметра и даже вообще без <>, какие тут еще впечатления.

Comment: @bipll по поводу второго - это понятно (автор просто пытался добиться хоть чего-то разными способами), но первое... Вы исходите из того, что человеку это должно быть известно априори. Но вот человек не знает этого. И я, кстати, тоже не знал (хотя сообразил про хвостовую нотацию). То что вам что-то известно, не означает, что это известно всем остальным.

Comment: Проблема в том что действительно в первую очередь ввёл в заблуждение компилятор, где он пишет list.h ...., изучаю С ++ по учебнику( и это не первый) в нём вообще всё создаётся в одном файле .cpp и нечего толком не объяснено, в попытке найти годное объяснение как на английском так и на русском, для конкретно моего случая завершилось неудачно. Да сейчас я понимаю отчётливо и ясно что компилятор просто просил написать typename перед ..., но на тот момент когда я тупо методом проб и ошибок, догадок пытался понять что не так, в ступор вводила ситуация когда не было шаблона логика прослеживалась.

Comment: @ДанилБрагин посоветую вам книгу Прата по С++ - замечательная книга, особенно для новичков (когда начинал изучать читал Кернела и Ритчи - ничего не понял!). Ну а в качестве спарвочника по стандартным библиотекам - Джосаттис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых хотелось бы сказать: вопрос не имеет отношение к "производному" классу, так как у вас нет наследования. У вас просто определение класса включено в пространство другого класса.

Что касается проблемы: компилятор просто не видит этого определения, вам нужен auto! Вот так:

```
template <typename Data>
auto List<Data>::find (Data d) -> List<Data>::Node *
```

Добавочка к ответу:

По поводу этой проблемы интересовался у своего препода с кураса по С++: проблема сдесь в парсере, так как он не может точно сказать тип ли это, но можно помочь ему это сделать таким образом:

```
template <class Data>
typename  List<Data>::Node * List<Data>::find (Data d){
```

Тобишь указав ключевое слово `typename` перед указанием типа возвращаемого функцией значения. Этот способ также указал ниже @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: Спасибо большое, да я просто немного перепутал понятия при описании проблемы. Честно говоря впервые вижу что вы написали, ещё раз спасибо буду разбираться дальше с данным языком.

Comment: @ДанилБрагин это плохо, что не слышали - эта фишка именно для классов сделана. Для вот таких вот случаев)

Comment: это удобно и очень полезно, но  единственный способ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan кстати, может прозвучать странно, но я сам до конца не понимаю почему так... Всмысле я понял что нужно сделать так, но вот почему нужно именно так - не до конца понял. Не объясните если знаете? Заодно можно будет дополнить ответ.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  обьяснять для меня это самая трудная задача, особенно на русском.  Но  вечером, когда буду свободен, то  попробую поделиться знанием. И еще, вы  достаточно грамотный и вежливый человек, и не мне вам обьяснять.  Да, просто поделюсь знанием...

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, можно убрать `List<Data>::` в возвращаемом типе и написать еще короче: `template <typename Data>
auto List<Data>::find (Data d) -> Node *`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, верно, так как сдесь уже используется нужное пространство имен

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch насколько я понял `template <class Data>
auto List<Data>::find (Data d) -> Node *` при такой записи данный оператор "->" говорит что предпочтительней использовать данный тип "Node *", так как оператор auto позволяет компилятору подобрать тип самому. Я прав?

Comment: @ДанилБрагин Не "предпочтительней", а просто говорит использовать `Node *`. `auto` здесь никак [не связан](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224325/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-when-using-c-trailing-return-type) с автоматическим определением типа.

Comment: @ДанилБрагин Кстати, вот еще один вариант решения, который компилятор предлагает в тексте ошибки: `template <class Data> typename List<Data>::Node * List<Data>::find (Data d)`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я понял ... мдя я просто не до конца понимал что он от меня хочет, недавно столкнулся с шаблонами ещё не знал что есть такой оператор `typename`, спасибо

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, в выражении  auto List<Data>::find (Data d) -> List<Data>::Node *   auto не говорит компилятору, что он должен определить тип, он только дает ему команду искать возвращаемый тип в конце функции  а именно  List<Data>::Node *  ( хотя в начале уже указан  область видимости, а выражение   List<Data>::Node * List<Data>::find (Data d)   дается команду компилятору поискать тип  Node  в области видимости  List<Data>, а он определен  в приватной области шаблонного класса, и  просто нет доступа к нему извне

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я тоже так сначала подумал, но вот только если Node вывести в public - все равно ничего не получится, пробовал.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  потому что класс шаблонный, и пока не будет спеуиализирован, компилятору не будет известен тип,  определенный в нем и зависящий от аргумента шаблона. Только в точке инстанции компилятор сможет определить тип   Node. Вот еслибы не было в нем Data d, тогда  все было бы в порядке, в условии приватной области. Я  могу не очень понятно выражаться, но надеюсь вы поймете о чем я

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вроде понятно

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, рад  быть полезен